# Is it possible to have inbound UDP /listen UDP packets in Azure Function / Azure App service

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

To my understanding it seems it is not possible to have inbound UDP traffic to an Azure App service or an Azure function. Is that a correct understanding?
Even when we use VNet integration it is only to have an outbound UDP traffic and not inbound. Is that a correct understanding?
Are there any other ways to allow inbound UDP packets to Azure app service or Azure function via any other Azure components.

I believe Azure cloud service , worker roles are some options but they do not have features like auto scale etc. But if these are a viable solution please do let known.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It would help to elaborate on your scenario, so that folks can provide better suggestions.

Comment: Please read [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service doesn't support listening on UDP. It only listens on HTTP, HTTPS and other corresponding TCP ports needed to support additional functionality like remote debugging, ftp etc. [Click here for more details](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening). There is [Private Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint) feature available, but it doesn't cover the aspect you are looking for.

Have you looked at VM Scale Sets?

- [Overview of autoscale with Azure virtual machine scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview)